# How should I know what's the quality of an SSD drive?

Tags: ssd, ultrabook

I would like to buy an ultrabook equipped with an SSD drive.

There are different kinds of SSD built in. Slower and faster. How should I know which one is faster?

Comment: It should list the data transfer rate of the drive somewhere. If it's a 7mm it's likely around 500 mb/s max. I might add that these transfer rates are a tad misleading as they don't account for the lag created by accessing smaller individual blocks of the ssd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for the data transfer speed of the drive both write and read. Also if the company has it listed you may want to look for Mean time to failure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm especially interested in Samsung NP900X3D-A03, but I couldn't find such information about data transfer speed. It sims to such info about SSD speed are for some reason hidden from consumers.

Comment: Alot of times the resellers do not have them listed, but it may be on the datasheet. Also alot of forums do SSD testing and have benchmarked speeds listed..